# My laptop is working very slow

Tags: windows-10

My laptop have operating system of Windows 10.

RAM is 4GB and Processor is 2.4 GHz.

But my laptop working is too slow when plugged-in to charging..

When I unplug the charger from laptop then it will become in normal working speed.

I don't know, what is the issue on my laptop and how I can solve it.

Comment: This question really makes no sense to me. Charging should not reduce speed in any way.

Comment: I'm guessing it's due to a setting in a power plan that is applied when the laptop is plugged in. Check the advanced power settings: Press Start, search for "power options" and open it. Click "Change plan settings" next to the active plan, then click "Change advanced power settings". Scroll down to "Processor power management" and expand it. Expand "Maximum processor state" and verify it is not limited to a certain percentage when the laptop is plugged in.